# SQLite creating table name using a variable

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, create-table

I was wondering if it was possible to use the datetime module in python to create day-specific tables so that the table's name is the date itself.

```
date_object = datetime.date.today()
sqlite_create_transfer_table = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS date_object (
                                sender TEXT NOT NULL,
                                recipient TEXT NOT NULL,
                                ID text NOT NULL,
                                Size NOT NULL,
                                Colour NOT NULL,
                                Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL);'''
```

However this just makes the table titled 'date_object' rather than using the variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! <3

Comment: It is generally problematic to want to do this, as it creates multiple tables that you now need to manage instead of one table to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.date.today()` will return a `datetime.date` object which you must convert to a string, but even then a string like `2022-03-05` is not a valid name for SQLite.
You must enclose it between square brackets or backticks or double quotes.

Try this:

```
date_object = datetime.date.today()
sqlite_create_transfer_table = f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [%s](
                                sender TEXT NOT NULL,
                                recipient TEXT NOT NULL,
                                ID text NOT NULL,
                                Size NOT NULL,
                                Colour NOT NULL,
                                Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL);""" % date_object
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the query something like this:

```
sqlite_create_transfer_table = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '+date_object+' (
                            sender TEXT NOT NULL,
                            recipient TEXT NOT NULL,
                            ID text NOT NULL,
                            Size NOT NULL,
                            Colour NOT NULL,
                            Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL);'''
```

Comment: That didn't work, the table is just titled '+date_object+' now

Comment: use this
sqlite_create_transfer_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+date_object+" (
                            sender TEXT NOT NULL,
                            recipient TEXT NOT NULL,
                            ID text NOT NULL,
                            Size NOT NULL,
                            Colour NOT NULL,
                            Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL);"